# How to determine why the connected host is different from request URL in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, networking

Trying to connect to bookdepository.com I occasionally notice that I get redirected through some shady affiliate link before landing on the site. I type the domain in the address bar and hit enter, the call first goes through a domain called `www.httpslink.me` then redirected to go.magik.ly then to awin affiliate network and finally to bookdepository. Here's a screenshot of the initial request:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out why this happens. You can see that while the request URL is bookdepository the contacted host is httpslink.me. My question is what determines the host that will be contacted. I logged the network traffic through chrome://net-export/  and there is no mention of an initial request to bookdepository, it goes straight to httpslink.me

Comment: This just happened to me. These are my extensions: https://pasteboard.co/JNBg6eb.png
Do you use one of those? If yes that's the extension adding the affiliate redirects. Please let me know which one

Comment: @Costantin I don't use any of those extensions. This problem stopped happening on its own and one my of my extensions was auto-disabled and marked by "this extension contains malware" note. In my case the extension was "enable right click". Malware authors constantly buy somewhat popular extensions to infect. It's a shame chrome doesn't have the tools to easily pinpoint who the culprit is.